# Unix Bash script causing git clone to not work

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell, unix

I have a bash script (script1.sh) where I perform a git clone. 
Then, from that repository, I run a another script (script2.sh) which runs fine.
I run script2.sh just fine, but the git repo is non existant. Any folder just isn't there. If I run the git clone on the command line, it clones it just fine.
Why is my script no git cloning my repo correctly?

How I run the first script.

```
sudo bash script1.sh
```

script1.sh

```
cd /home/ubuntu
git clone http://mygit-thing.com/myrepository.git localfolder
#run script from the repo
sudo bash localfolder/script2.sh
```

script2.sh

```
~ Some unrelated unix commands
```

Notes: I tried looking at the /home/ubuntu folder and could not find it. It's not a "hidden" file as well.

Comment: When you run git clone on the command line, do you run it with sudo as well?

Comment: If you can run script2.sh, it has to be *somewhere*. Have you tried find command?

Comment: @Bhavesh, I don't think so, he changed into his home directory, so he can just use a relative path name.

Comment: script1.sh is successfully running the script2.sh that is inside the repo. Which tells me that it cloned atleast in the scope of the first script

Comment: Cloning means it actually donwloads the files, so the scope doesn't really matter. It must still be present somewhere, you just can't find it for some reason. I tried to do the exact same thing, works for me. Something is weird here.

Comment: I'll do a find when I wake up. It's quite late now.

Comment: is this folder "localfolder" already exists in the same location ??

Comment: The git clone will create the localfolder. It is not existing before git clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could solve your problem replace your `script1.sh`:

```
home=/home/ubuntu
folder=$home/localfolder
git clone http://mygit-thing.com/myrepository.git $folder
#run script from the repo
bash $folder/script2.sh
```

if it does not work, it is maybe possible that you are not allowed to write on `$home` because of your current user permissions or because your fs is read-only You can check that by executing `mount` without option, it will list all mounted fs.

Another point, sudoing from inside a script is not recommended. Currently you are basically sudoing on a sudo. If you want to be sure the right user is executing your script, you better check the current id than doing nested sudo.

Comment: Thanks, in my first script, I forgot I cd'd to a different directory and forgot to go back to my original directory. Absolute paths fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

As @jibe suggested, you're calling bash from sudo, which will call `bash` from different location. Provide full path to the local git repository.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue during to write blue-green deployment script , I resolved calling with bash.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 bash  /home/ubuntu/deployment-guru/green-deployment.sh
```

green-deployment.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/ubuntu/my_api && git pull origin blue-green-jenkins-integration
```

before calling without bash i was facing following issue

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.